# Why are there problems using map in an IF statement?

Tags: netlogo

Why won't the following run?

```
if (map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1] [2] [3]) [show 100]
```

The following produces 'true' as an output:

```
show (map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1] [2] [3])
```

so I expected the first statement above to be the same as:

```
if true [show 100]
```

(P.S. in my full version the lists are longer but are collapsed into a single true/false using reduce.)

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the output of map is being put into a list, so the following works: if (map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1] [2] [3]) = [true] [show 100]

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on ThomasC's comment, map always produces a list, even if it only has one element.  So

```
(map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1] [2] [3])
```

does produce `[true]`. Thus

```
(map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1 2] [2 3] [3 5])
```

will produce `[true true]`.  `reduce` is helpful here,

```
reduce AND (map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1 2] [2 3] [3 5])
```

will produce a simple `true` by "anding" all the elements of the map output, and

```
reduce AND (map [ [a b c] -> a + b = c ] [1 2] [2 3] [3 6])
```

will produce a simple `false`.